# Can't play gifv as webm anymore?

Tags: html, video, webm

I'm trying to play "new" gifv's as webm. But it doesnt seem to work. But old gifv's are working

```
//new, not working
<video autoplay><source src="http://i.imgur.com/ISNuf1P.webm" type="video/webm"></video>
//old, working
<video autoplay><source src="http://i.imgur.com/BK7Lhgp.webm" type="video/webm"></video>
```

Can someone explain this or find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Simply change from gifv to mp4 instead.